# How to remove Aloha Editor from DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery, aloha-editor

I am using Aloha to edit contents on a client's website and want to remove all extra DOM elements and attributes when I save.

A paragraph tag goes from:

```
<p></p>
```

to:

```
<p id="79a2eed4-1d7d-55a9-1c44-d384d35edf4f" 
    class="aloha-editable aloha-editable-active" 
    contenteditable="true" style=""></p>
```

I want to remove all of those added elements. Is there a destroy call in the Aloha API that I have missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following reverts an editable to its non-editable form

```
$('#editable').mahalo();
```

This should also remove the attributes added by aloha (classes, contenteditable=true, etc.).

I have [added it](https://github.com/alohaeditor/Aloha-Editor/commit/adbdf4ac49edc2c1b93ec5a96615b27610701667) to the official documentation.

Comment: I called .mahalo(). I followed the js code in aloha.js and saw the classes, attributes being removed. However, the hidden toolbar DIV is still in the FORM. Any suggestion?

Comment: @clam, there is currently no built-in functionality to get rid of the toolbar div. However, you can just remove all elements attached to the body with class .aloha and reattach them when you need the toolbar again.